# someone trying to SQLi server using sqlmap

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap

Someone is trying to SQLi my domain using sqlmap. I'm getting a lot of errors from mysql.

My server access log shows:

> > - -  HTTP/1.1" 200 10559 "-" "sqlmap/1.0.4.0#dev (http://sqlmap.org)"

I have tried blocking the IP but the IP keeps changing. How to block sqlmap from server?

Comment: Could you provide some more log files for us to look at? A pastebin will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an agent check, which will stop those who are dumb enough not to change the agent - block any request with an agent string that includes 'sqlmap'

However, I will note that if you are actually getting SQL errors, that is a sign that you may be vulnerable to SQL Injection.  If you are properly using parameterized queries / DAOs / PDOs, you should not get a SQL error.  An attacker should never be able to get your SQL to error - if they can, they may be able to change its execution.